# Parsing XML contained in a string using an XSL via JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, entity-framework-ctp5

This is my XML:

```
var x="<page><item>1</item></page>";
```

My XML is stored in a JavaScript string.

I am trying to make some changes to this XML using XSL. I want to apply this XSL to this XML via JavaScript. So I have used JQuery:

```
$('#output').xslt({xmlURL: '??',xslUrl: 'Test.xsl'});
```

Here the xmlURL is an XML file, but the input is a string containing XML. So how do I apply this XSL to the XML string ?

Comment: Are you using the XSLT plugin as noted?

Answer (score 1):

Use the XML option, assuming you are using the [XSLT plugin](http://www.jongma.org/webtools/jquery/xslt/).

```
$('#output').xslt({
   xml: x,
   xslUrl: 'Test.xsl'
});
```

Comment: Any idea how could we pass a parameter to test.xsl while calling the xslURL..

say something like xslUrl: 'Test.xsl?param="abc"'


and retrive the value of this parameter in my xsl file ??

Comment: You really ought to put another question together for that one. Look at: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize